# Understanding parent and controller in Tkinter __init__

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to understand what the below code means:

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
```

What are `self`, `parent` and `controller`? What is the role and scope of these tools here?

I believe `self` is similar to `this` in Java, but what's the use of `parent` and `controller`?

Later in the code flow I can see:

```
button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
      command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
```

There is a function already defined called `show_frame`, but why is the controller being used to call this function?

Comment: They are parameters to the method. What is confusing you about them? There is nothing special about `__init__` here, except that it is called automatically using the parameters passed to the instantiation call.

Comment: *"I believe self is similar to this in Java"* - yes. *"what's the use of parent and controller?"* - they're just two other initialisation parameters. In Tkinter, you generally pass the `parent` widget within which the new widget sits to each new widget to define a tree for the whole UI. `controller` is apparently something that can be used to control the overall UI, rather than make a widget responsible for global changes.

Comment: Code appears to be from http://stackoverflow.com/q/29444725/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe: actually, the original code came from this answer of mine from 2011: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/7432. The question you link to refers to a tutorial on the internet which seems to have copied that answer almost verbatim -- and without attribution :-(

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that the `parent` and `controller` arguments have nothing intrinsically to do with `tkinter`, their meaning is entirely defined by the context in which they're being used (i.e. what the rest of the code in class is).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Roughly speaking, the original code<sup>1</sup> attempted to use a pseudo-[MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (model, view and controller) architecture. Though without the "model" part -- there was just a "view" (some frames) and a "controller" (the main application). Hence, the reference to a controller object. The original code was actually written to show how to "stack" frames, so it's MVC implementation is very shallow and under-documented since that wasn't the point of the example.

To answer your specific questions:

**self** represents the current object. This is a common first parameter for any method of a class. As you suggested, it's similar to Java's *this*.

**parent** represents a widget to act as the parent of the current object. All widgets in tkinter except the root window require a parent (sometimes also called a *master*)

**controller** represents some other object that is designed to act as a common point of interaction for several pages of widgets. It is an attempt to decouple the pages. That is to say, each page doesn't need to know about the other pages. If it wants to interact with another page, such as causing it to be visible, it can ask the controller to make it visible.

You asked *"There is a function already defined called show_frame, but why is the controller being used to call this function?"* Notice that `show_frame` is defined in a separate class, in this case the main program class. It is not defined in the other classes. For the other classes to be able to call it, they must call it on an instance of the main class. That instance is named `controller` in the context of these other classes.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note: even though you likely found the original code in an online tutorial, it originally came from this stackoverflow answer: [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter/7557028#7557028)

Comment: just one question, so what ever classes are initialized at the Main Loop of a tkinter program, throws a "controller" to the class being initialized?? so this is the controller which is caught and initialized at __INIT__????

Comment: @VasanthNagKV: "throw" is an odd choice of words. But yes, the main program is being passed to each object as the "controller" parameter.