# Tkinter input to excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, tkinter, xlwt

I am working on a Tkinter app that takes input and outputs excel data. I cannot get the entry for size or any other entry field. I want the entry to be obtained and stored in the excel file when the user selects finish order. What change does the code need?
so far everything works except that I do not know how to get the data from the entry because when the button is clicked it runs the code again and thus erases the values.

```
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
import xlwt as xl
from datetime import datetime

style1 = xl.XFStyle()
style1.num_format_str = "D-MM-YY"

wb = xl.Workbook()


sheet1 = wb.add_sheet("Sheet1", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
sheet1.write(0, 0, datetime.now(), style1)

sheet1.write(0, 1, "Item")
sheet1.write(0, 2, "Size")
sheet1.write(0, 3, "Quantity")


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Furniture order")


item_label = tk.Label(text="Select your item ")
item_label.grid(column= 5, row=0)


def destroy ():
    item_label.destroy()
    table_button.destroy()
    chair_button1.destroy()


def options ():
    size_label = tk.Label(text="Enter the size")
    size_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
    color_label = tk.Label(text="Enter the color")
    color_label.grid(column=0, row=1)
    quantity_label = tk.Label(text="Enter the quantity")
    quantity_label.grid(column=0, row=2)

    done_button = tk.Button(text="Finish the order", command=get_data)
    done_button.grid(column=1, row=4)



def entry ():
    size_entry = tk.Entry(window)
    size_entry.grid(column=2, row=0)
    color_entry = tk.Entry()
    color_entry.grid(column=2, row=1)
    quantity_entry = tk.Entry()
    quantity_entry.grid(column=2, row=2)

    return size_entry.get()

def get_data ():
    size = entry()
    sheet1.write(1, 1, "table")
    sheet1.write(1, 2, size)
    wb.save("test2.xls")




def t_d ():
    destroy()
    options()
    entry()


def c_d ():
    destroy()
    options()
    entry()



chair_button1 = tk.Button(text="Chair", command=t_d)
chair_button1.grid(column=0, row=3)

table_button = tk.Button(text="Table", command=c_d)
table_button.grid(column=10, row=3)


wb.save("test2.xls")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: While it's possible to "fix" the problem you're encountering, there really isn't a good way to do so with the approach implemented in your existing code (although doing so would be fairly simple as illustrated in my now deleted answer). Instead I _strongly_ suggest you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/355230) because I think doing things the way it does would provide a much better basic architecture for what you appear to want to do in your `tkinter`-based application. Also take a look at this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32865334/355230).